# What type should I use to for definite type ids of a media in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Currently, I'm querying a media through an API. It returns something like this:

```
{
  media_id: 42,
  media_type: 1,
  ...
}
```

where `media_type` can only be `1 (image), 2 (video), 3 (audio)`.

I'm declaring the Media interface as

```js
export interface Media {
  media_id: number;
  media_type: number; // (1: Video; 2: Audio; 3: Image)
  ...
}
```

which doesn't seem to be a good idea since `media_type` requires the coders to read the doc and remember which number corresponds to which type.

What is the proper type to use with this? I'm thinking about `enum` but I can't think of the way to turn this into an enum.

**Note**: I'm pretty sure this must be a duplicate of a question. I've tried to search for it but I can't seem to find a good keywords to get the desired results. Sorry about that.

Comment: @phuzi Thanks! I'll try it out and see if it answers my question

Comment: You can use union of literal types: `media_type: 1 | 2 | 3`